# Draw in java like windows paint

Tags: java, swing, colors, draw, paint

I made a java app to draw, like Windows Paint, I do not know if it's better to do it in two classes, or left unattended in a class, and on the other side. Do I can help make it more efficient?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class MyPaint{
        public static void main(String[] args){     

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Just Paint");    

    Container content = frame.getContentPane();

    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());      

    final PadDraw drawPad = new PadDraw();      

    content.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 68));
    panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 68));
    panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 68));

            JButton twoX = new JButton ("2");
            twoX.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.clear();
        }
    });             


    JButton yellowButton = new JButton("YELLOW");
    yellowButton.setForeground(new Color(204, 204, 0));

    yellowButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.yellow();
        }

    });


    JButton greenButton = new JButton("GREEN");
    greenButton.setForeground(new Color(0, 204, 0));

    greenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.green();
        }
    });

    JButton redButton = new JButton("RED");
    redButton.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));

    redButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.red();
        }
    });

    JButton blueButton = new JButton("BLUE");
    blueButton.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

    blueButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.blue();
        }
    });

    JButton blackButton = new JButton("BLACK");

    blackButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.black();
        }
    });
    greenButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 20));
    redButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 20));
    yellowButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 20));
    blueButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 20));
    greenButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,20));


    panel.add(blackButton);
    panel.add(blueButton);
    panel.add(redButton);
    panel.add(greenButton);
    panel.add(yellowButton);


    content.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JRadioButton rdbtnPx = new JRadioButton("3 px");
    panel.add(rdbtnPx);

    JRadioButton rdbtnPx_1 = new JRadioButton("5 px");
    panel.add(rdbtnPx_1);

    JRadioButton rdbtnPx_2 = new JRadioButton("12 px");
    panel.add(rdbtnPx_2);


    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(rdbtnPx);
    bg.add(rdbtnPx_1);
    bg.add(rdbtnPx_2);

    rdbtnPx.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.small();
        }
    });
    rdbtnPx_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.medium();
        }
    });
    rdbtnPx_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.big();
        }
    });

    JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    clearButton.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    clearButton.setFont(UIManager.getFont("TextArea.font"));

    clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            drawPad.clear();
        }
    });
    panel.add(clearButton);

    frame.setSize(454, 440);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}


class PadDraw extends JComponent{

private Image image;    
private Graphics2D graphics2D;  
private int currentX , currentY , oldX , oldY ;

public PadDraw(){
    setDoubleBuffered(false);
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            oldX = e.getX();
            oldY = e.getY();
        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            currentX = e.getX();
            currentY = e.getY();
            if(graphics2D != null)
            graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
            repaint();
            oldX = currentX;
            oldY = currentY;
        }

    });

}   

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    if(image == null){
        image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
        graphics2D = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        clear();

    }
    g.drawImage(image, 5, 5, null);
}

public void clear(){
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.white);
    graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
    repaint();
}

public void red(){
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.red);
    repaint();
}

public void black(){
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
    repaint();
}

public void yellow(){
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.yellow);
    repaint();
}

public void blue(){
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.blue);
    repaint();
}

public void green(){
    graphics2D.setPaint(Color.green);
    repaint();
}
public void small(){
    graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));;
}
public void medium(){
    graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));;
}
public void big(){
    graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(12));;
}

}
```

Comment: If this is your final working program, i suggest you go over to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and read their requirements and guidelines for asking a question, then format your question accordingly and it can be migrated.

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

It means that your class should change only for one reason.

Keeping all the code you wrote in only one class is breaking this principle. So split it in different classes each one doing only one thing.

Comment: this is so generic I might as well open the bible